# PetPoco Mapping ignore column

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, petapoco

I am doing an insert into a table using petapoco. The insert was working fine until I introduced a property on the class that was calculated and didn't map to any column in the table. Now the code breaks because it is not able to map that property(isAdmin) to a column in the table. I tried adding the attribute [PetaPoco.Ignore] to the class property isAdmin but that didnt help.

This is how I am doing the mapping

```
 For<Users>()
                .TableName("users")
                .PrimaryKey("id",false)
                .Columns(x =>
                {
                    x.Column(y => y.id, "id");
                    x.Column(y => y.UserType, "user_type");
                    x.Column(y => y.isAdmin,"");//How do I tell petapoco not to map this to any column?
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple omit it from the manual mapping or use `[ResultColumn]` attribute if not